# Date range filter using JQuery DataTable with Salesforce as server side

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery, datatable

I have a requirement where I need to put all the TXN__c records in a table where I have more than 50,000+ records that's why I use server-side. On load I can now get what I want. My next challenge here is filtering the Date__c using the datepicker from the vf page to the controller. Hope someone can help me on this. This is what I have right now.

VFPage:

```
<apex:page doctype="html-5.0" controller="AccountHistory2" tabstyle="Account" sidebar="false" readonly="true" cache="false" showheader="true" standardstylesheets="false">
<apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="dates1" title="Filter by Date">
           <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                Start Date: <input type="text" id="min" class="datepicker" value="{!startDate}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                End Date: <input type="text" id="max" class="datepicker" value="{!endDate}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <input type='button' id="btn_search" value="Search"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
<script>
var url = '{!$Page.AccountHistoryTableHelper}?id={!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}';
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Datepicker
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        "dateFormat": "MM-DD-YYYY",
        "changeYear": true
    });
    
    $.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'console';
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        'destroy': true,
        'pagingType': 'simple_numbers',
        'aaSorting': [[0, 'desc']],
        'processing': true,
        'serverSide': true,
        'serverMethod': 'post',
        'searching': true,
        'ajax': {
            'url': url,
            'data': function(data){
                var from_date = $('#min').val();
                var to_date = $('#max').val();
                
                console.log('from_date: '+from_date);
                console.log('to_date: '+to_date);
                data.fromDate = from_date;
                data.toDate = to_date;
                
            }
        },
        'columnDefs': [{ targets: [10, 11, 12, 13], className: 'dt-body-right' },
                       { targets: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], className: 'dt-body-center' }],
        'columns': [
            { 'data': 'Date__c',
             render: function(data, type, row){
                 //console.log(data);
                 if(type === 'sort' || type === 'type'){
                     return data;
                 }
                 return moment(data).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
             }
            },
            { 'data': 'Bill_To_Member__r.Name' },
            { 'data': 'RecordType.Name' },
            { 'data': 'Name' }
        ]
    });
    
    //Search button
    $('#btn_search').on('click', function(){
        table.draw();
    });
    
});

$.fn.DataTable.ext.pager.numbers_length = 10;
</script>
```

but when clicking the search button it doesn't filter by date.
[image]

Hope someone can help me on this one. Thank you!